# Cron-style scheduler that runs only once, but is run on multiple hosts

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a node.js app that's going to run on multiple machines (potentially on a serverless environment).

I'd like to run something like:

```
setInterval(() => {
  Scanner.process()
}, 1000*60)
```

The problem is, when this same code is scaled up and run on 5 machines, it'll trigger 5 times every minute, instead of just once.

I thought i could use some sort of Redis lock to make sure the function is run only once at that schedule, no matter how many machines run it.

Any ideas on how to best approach this?

*P.S. I can't really rely on a hostname and make the code only run there*

Comment: Does it have to run at regular intervals?  How precise is the timing requirement?

Comment: Doesn't have to be precise at all, I'm fine with having on a simple interval like this OR at a fixed interval (the first second of every minute)

Comment: How damaging is it for the job to get run more than necessary?

Comment: that's what i want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to solve this without using a central resource like a database to decide who is going to run the job.

You could have all servers run the job, kicking off the interval at random times...

```
setTimeout(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        Scanner.process()
    }, 1000 * 60 * num_machines)
}, 1000 * 60 * num_machines * Math.random())
```

Downside is you need to know how many other machines are running.

Not sure if there's a way to do this without some kind of knowledge of the other machines.

If the result of the job is available to all machines you could have them use that info to align their schedules.  For example, if the last job start time is broadly available, each machine could defer execution of it's own schedule.  I.e. as long as the job has been run, I won't run it myself until it looks like it hasn't been run in a while.

Comment: Thanks for the info - i can't have any awareness of other machines. That's why I think using a Redis lock might be the only way - i'll look into it

Comment: Can each machine see the job results?  Might be better to manage the schedule that way vs. fight for a lock before running.